# Unable to trigger Mention in teams when creating a new group conversation

Tags: microsoft-teams

I can create a new group conversation and have teams recognize my mention (it creates the popup div containing the correct user info for the user's name in the message), but it **does not actually trigger a notification** activity on mobile or desktop platforms - which is the part I actually need to work.

```
var channelData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
channelData["teamsChannelId"] = yourTeamsChannelID;
IMessageActivity newMessage = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
newMessage.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
newMessage.Text = "Hello <at>Guy</at>.  This is a newly created reply chain.";

var mention = new Mention();
mention.Mentioned = new ChannelAccount("correctIdGoesHere", "Guy");
mention.Text = "<at>Guy</at>";

newMessage.Entities = new List<Entity>();
newMessage.Entities.Add(mention);

ConversationParameters conversationParams = new ConversationParameters(
    isGroup: true,
    bot: null,
    members: null,
    topicName: "Test Conversation",
    activity: (Activity)newMessage,
    channelData: channelData);
var result = await connector.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug and has been entered in our bug database.

Comment: Thank you.  Is there any way for me to track the bug or do you have any expectations on when it might be resolved?